# Copy Features giving ERROR 000210: Cannot create output in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, error-000210

I have an issue where I'm trying to save separate feature classes for each route in an already solved closest facility problem, and one seemingly arbitrary route won't save. I tried to look at the original feature class that had all the routes, and I couldn't find anything particularly notable about this one route. Furthermore, just to get an idea of whether there was more than one feature that had a problem, I tried a try-except in arcpy, but every feature class after the one seemingly arbitrary broken one saved just fine. Moreover, when I used Model Builder to create the feature classes, everything worked just fine, without any hitches. But I have to use Python, and it's just not working. Can anyone give any pointers?

Here's the code, although I'm not convinced it's even going to be helpful. (Note: Obviously, the code looks kind of rough, because a good bit of it was exported from Model Builder, and I just reworked what wouldn't export. Also, I'm well aware that turning the features into layers, doing a select, and copying the layers back to features is inelegant in comparison to simply doing a select_analysis, but that's just the last version of the code. Neither way worked.):

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

# Script arguments
Building_network_1_nodes_1_1 = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Building_network_1_nodes_1_1" 

# Local variables:
Test01_ND = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_ND"
Test01 = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01"
Test01__3_ = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01"

# Process: Make Closest Facility Layer
outNALayer = arcpy.MakeClosestFacilityLayer_na(Test01_ND, "Closest_Facility_Model01", "Length", "TRAVEL_TO", "", "2", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "", "NO_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "", "NOT_USED")

# Process: Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(Building_network_1_nodes_1_1, r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_FModel", "node_type = 3")

# Process: Add Locations
arcpy.AddLocations_na("Closest_Facility_Model01", "Facilities", r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_FModel", "", "5000 Meters", "", "Building_network_1mz_1_1 SHAPE;Building_network_1_nodes_1_1 SHAPE;Test01_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "INCLUDE", "Building_network_1mz_1_1 #;Building_network_1_nodes_1_1 #;Test01_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Select (2)
arcpy.Select_analysis(Building_network_1_nodes_1_1, r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_IModel", "node_type = 1")

# Process: Add Locations (2)
arcpy.AddLocations_na("Closest_Facility_Model01", "Incidents", r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_IModel", "", "5000 Meters", "", "Building_network_1mz_1_1 SHAPE;Building_network_1_nodes_1_1 SHAPE;Test01_ND_Junctions NONE", "MATCH_TO_CLOSEST", "APPEND", "NO_SNAP", "5 Meters", "INCLUDE", "Building_network_1mz_1_1 #;Building_network_1_nodes_1_1 #;Test01_ND_Junctions #")

# Process: Solve
Solved = arcpy.na.Solve(outNALayer, "SKIP", "TERMINATE", "")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Routes", r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_Routes")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Facilities", r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_Facil")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Incidents", r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_Incid")

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Script arguments
Routes = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_Routes"
Facilities = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_FModel"
Incidents = r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01\\Test01_IModel"

# Local variables:
Test01 = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01"
NATest01_071414_gdb = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb"
Test01_A = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01_A"

u = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Routes, "IncidentID")][-1]

for v in range(1, u + 1):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Routes, "Route" + str(v))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Route" + str(v), "NEW_SELECTION", """ "IncidentID" = """ + str(v))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Routes, r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01_A\\Route_" + str(v))
    print "Route " + str(v) + " exported."
```

The whole rest of the script would work until the last part. Here's an abridged version of the print log:

```
Route 1 exported.
Route 2 exported.
...
...
...
Route 37 exported.
Route 38 exported.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/TestFolder/Test_01", line 53, in <module>
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Routes, r"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01_A\\Route_" + str(v))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2429, in CopyFeatures
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\TestGeo.gdb\\Test01_A\Route_39
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).
```

I'm at a loss. I have no idea why I'd get that error for that particular feature class. It seems so, like I said, arbitrary. Like I said before, too, it works just fine in Model Builder, but I get this hiccup with arcpy. If anyone has ideas, I'd like to hear them. I feel like I've done all the obvious things, so far.

Comment: Are there actually features where IncidentID = 39? BTW, in python you can use \" to insert a quote instead of """, that would change the definition query to "\"IncidentID\" = " + str(v) which to me is a little more readable, but I'm bias.

Comment: Have you tried using the Copy Features tool dialog to run the step that fell over manually with exactly the same parameters that are fed to it by the script?  To do this it looks like you will also need to run the prior two steps (i.e. Make Feature Layer and Select Layer By Attribute).

Comment: if you use try/except in your loop, does it jump #39 and work for the following ?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes, there are features in 39. Like I said previously, it worked just fine in Model Builder. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in arcpy. Also, thanks for the readability tip.

Comment: @PolyGeo - I haven't tried that set of tasks manually on it (or a manual Select (Analysis)), but everything did work fine in Model Builder, previously. It's only not working in arcpy. That said, I should try your suggestion.

Comment: @radouxju - Yes, when I use try-except, it simply skips #39, and all the rest of the subsequent feature classes get saved without further issue.

Comment: Logically, if the code is working fine for all other values it must be bad data, for example if you've got an invalid geometry, try the Repair Geometry tool on your source data. If that doesn't work then the data source is probably slightly corrupt, importing into a new geodatabase can rectify this if it's not too broken; export to XML and import from XML workspace can also help for slightly corrupt data... Of course if a value contains an invalid character this could also be a problem, is IncidentID numeric or string?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. A selection set (the result of an SelectByLocation (intersection) between two polygon FCs) cannot be saved using CopyFeatures. Error 000210. The selection set can't be saved to a file geodatabase or a shapefile (e.g. C:\temp\delete.shp). Not with a python script. Not with the CopyFeatures tool in ArcCatalog. There are less than 1000 small features selected so size shouldn't be a problem. Maybe there's a problem with some strange geometry. Anyway, since this is a serious problem for me so I need to fix it fast. Oh yeah, I recently "upgraded" to 10.2.2 from 10.2.1

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE @FittyStim!  As a new user you will find some of our protocols that are quickly introduced in the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and fleshed out in the [Help](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help) can take a bit of getting used to.  A "me too answer" like this will normally get converted straight to a Comment so you may want to ask it as a [New Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, the issue sounds like corrupted input data. Run a `RepairGeometry_management` prior to your `CopyFeatures_management` on your inputs. I have read of other problems using `CopyFeatures_management`. I recommend using `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion` instead. It is essentially the same geoprocess, and I've never had or read about issues using it.